# Css file modified into temp php file in server (joomla)

Tags: php, css, file, parsing, joomla

I have added this below code for css reference.

```
JHTML::_('stylesheet', 'example.css', 'components/'._THISCOMPONENT.'/assets/css/');
```

It is working fine in local.But when i try to run it in the server, the css is not working due to this 
output html css link

```
&lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/com_fms/assets/css/css-3391b7d3949af1560b9927c0c3a672b2.php" type="text/css" /&gt;
```

Do anyone have idea on solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
```

By default this code work correct if it is added in template-file (templates/my_fantastic_template/index.php)

Try this code:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet('components/'._THISCOMPONENT.'/assets/css/example.css');
```

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i am sorry, i have tried it and its not working. The problem is wherever the css extension files are all available, they are  converted to temp file with php extension with out my knowledge.Is this due to  template changes.

Here is the similiar type of issue

http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070811044718AAsM3v8

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
```

instead

```
JHTML::_('stylesheet', 'example.css', 'components/'._THISCOMPONENT.'/assets/css/');
```

complet `/templates/system/css/system.css` with your url to the css file

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried it , due to some macros the css extension is not rendering. Do you have any idea?